# Expected Expression before ']' token

Tags: objective-c, expression

The code:

```
-(void) GoToMainMenu: (id) sender {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] sendCleanupToScene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade 
                                                transitionWithDuration:1 
                                               scene:[HelloWorldLayer  node: ]]
     ];
}
```

I repeatedly keep getting the error "Expected Expression before ']' token.

Comment: yeah I just saw my mistake and I was like *headsmack* and crawled to a dark corner

Comment: Close this as `Too Localized` and move on

Comment: BTW:  method names should begin with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't passing anything here.

```
[HelloWorldLayer  node: ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the parameter after `HelloWorldLayer  node:`:

```
scene:[HelloWorldLayer  node:<your parameter here> ]]
```